# What did Michael Talbot do to anger a demi-goddess?

Tags: tufo-verse

Littered throughout Mark Tufo's Tufo-verse (Zombie Fallout, Lycan Fallout, Indian Hill, etc.) there are references to Michael Talbot pissing off a demi-god as his source of misfortune.

From *Lycan Fallout 4*:

> "Again I said nothing. What could I say? She was right. From the
>   moment I'd told that demi-god to basically kiss my ass, there hadn't
>   been much in my life that wasn't dictated by the strangest of events
>   and the most savage of twists. Hell one time I'd gone straight from
>   cleaning my garage to confronting a yeti..."

The name "Poena" was mentioned in (I believe) *Mark's Merry Mayhem*.

Wikipedia say [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poena) regarding the Roman goddess Poena:

> In Roman mythology, Poena (also Poine) is the spirit of punishment and
>   the attendant of punishment to Nemesis, the goddess of divine
>   retribution. The Latin word poena, "pain, punishment, penalty", gave
>   rise to English words such as subpoena and pain. The original word is
>   the Ancient Greek poinḗ (ποινή), also meaning “penalty.”

***What are the specific details of the events surrounding when Mike angered a demi-god(dess) and where can they be found?***

Comment: "From the moment I'd told that demi-god to basically kiss my ass" that seems fairly straightforward to me, demi-god wanted something, asked for it and was denied possibly with colorful language.

Comment: @Revenant sounds about right, but I modified the question slightly to clarify that I am looking for details of the *events* surrounding him angering the demi-god (most definitely with the use of colorful language)

Answer (score 3):

According to the author (at least back in 2012) there hasn't been anything written about exactly what Mike did to anger Poena.

From [this comment](http://zombiefallout.blogspot.com/2012/03/first-500-words-zf6.html?showComment=1334077519409#c1369563315570584851) on [The first 500 words ZF6](http://zombiefallout.blogspot.com/2012/03/first-500-words-zf6.html):

> Hi Robert, first off thank you! And as for 6 being the last I honestly won't know until I've written about half of it. I really thought 5 was going to be it and I never got out of the opening scene I had laid out in my head. So there's still plenty of stuff for ZF6. As for Poena, she is the Goddess of Retribution and she has NOT been mentioned before. **Mike pissed her off (go figure)** and that is why he finds himself wandering through nightmares.

in the latest book of Shrouded World: Valhalla, Mike and Kalandar discuss Poena a little and it gives a more up to date answer than 2012, though the answer is still the same.

> Mike: "I've been told I have one continually screwing with my life."
>
> Kalandar: "Which one?
>
> Mike: "Poena"
>
> Kalandar actually winced and pulled back. "She is mean-spirited; did you insult her origins?"
>
> Mike:  She's female.  She still hasn't told me what I've done to make her furious.  Maybe she's angry because I don't know why she's angry."
>
> Kalandar: "I've met her - that could be the case."

Comment: I edited in what I think is the author's explanation you were referring to; if it isn't, you're welcome to [edit] something else in. Good find, anyway!

Comment: Lol for this being from before ZF6 released. ZF12 recently was finished and sent off for Audiobook recording, but good find.